# iphone web app css button :active not working

Tags: css, mobile-safari, iphone, iphone-web-app

i am coding an iphone web app and i am trying to change the background image of a button through css. The `:active` event however on the iphone safari browser doesnt work when i click on the button. Is there some css hotfix for this? thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try this, it should make it work: `<a ontouchstart="">Link</a>`. You can also apply it to the `body` element to fix more than one button at once.